# JavaFX: canvas does not display anything

Tags: canvas, javafx-2, fxml

I just began to study JavaFx. Sorry for the basic question, but I got stuck here for a couple of days.

I built a FXML based project, and want to display something in a Canvas. Canvas is embedded in a stackpane, and the stackpane is embedded in a FXML window. There is a button in the window, when I click it, the Canvas should display some shapes.

Now the problem is, the Canvas does not display anything. `ActionButtonStart` is the button action method. Thanks a lot!!

```
public class MainController implements Initializable{
    @FXML
    private StackPane windowHolder; 
    @FXML
    private Canvas mainCanvas;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        mainCanvas = new Canvas();
        windowHolder = new StackPane(); 
    }

    public void ActionButtonStart(ActionEvent event){
        //WindowNavigator.loadWindow(WindowNavigator.WINDOW_1_Welcome);
        final GraphicsContext gc = mainCanvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
        gc.clearRect(0, 0, mainCanvas.getWidth(), mainCanvas.getHeight());

        gc.setFill(Color.BLACK);
        gc.setFont(Font.getDefault());
        gc.fillText("hello   world!", 15, 50);

        gc.setLineWidth(5);
        gc.setStroke(Color.PURPLE);

        gc.strokeOval(10, 60, 30, 30);
        gc.strokeOval(60, 60, 30, 30);
        gc.strokeRect(30, 100, 40, 40);

                windowHolder.getChildren().add(mainCanvas);
    }

    public void setWindow(Node node) {
        windowHolder.getChildren().setAll(node);
    }   

}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `initialize()` method, you replace the `Canvas` and the `StackPane` defined in your FXML file with new instances. So when you modify the canvas in the `actionButtonStart` method, you're not initializing the one that's defined in FXML and displayed in your UI.

Remove the lines from the `initialize` method, and it will probably work.

You didn't post the code for your FXML file, but I would guess that the FXML file already adds the canvas to the stack pane. If that's the case, the line

```
windowHolder.getChildren().add(mainCanvas)
```

will generate an error at runtime (since the canvas is now added twice). You should add the canvas to the stack pane in FXML, and remove that line from the action handler.

Also review [Controller Method Event Handlers](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#controller_method_event_handlers) and ensure that you are referencing `ActionButtonStart` from your fxml via `onAction="#ActionButtonStart"`.  It's also a good idea to conform to Java method name conventions (e.g. call your method `actionButtonStart` instead of `ActionButtonStart`).